# C# NULL VALUES BEING INSERTED IN DB

Tags: c#, null, xmlreader

I am reading an XML file and saving the extracted data according to the elements of the XML file.
I am using XmlReader.
 BUT WHEN I AM RUNNING THE PROGRAM ... IT RUNS FINE BUT, only NULL values are being sent into my db.
My codes are as follows :

```
 using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{



    string org_id;
    string org_desig;
    string org_name;
    string add_1;
    string add_2;
    string add_3;
    string cityname;
    string countrycode;
    string countryname;
    string postalcode;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //  Load the XML file
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("PXMLF-8612013050420130606105906.xml");

        //  Loop over the XML file
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //  look for element
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                //  If the element is the one required
                if (reader.Name == "OrganizationID")
                {
                    org_id = (reader.ReadElementString());

                }

                if (reader.Name == "OrganisationDesignator")
                    {

                        org_desig = (reader.ReadElementString());
                    }

                if (reader.Name == "OrganizationName1")
                    {

                        org_name = (reader.ReadElementString());
                    }

                if (reader.Name == "AddressLine1")
                    {

                        add_1 = (reader.ReadElementString());
                    }

                if (reader.Name == "AddressLine2")
                    {

                        add_2 = (reader.ReadElementString());
                    }

                if (reader.Name == "AddressLine3")
                    {

                        add_3 = (reader.ReadElementString());
                    }

                if (reader.Name == "CityName")
                    {

                         cityname = (reader.ReadElementString());
                    }

                if (reader.Name == "CountryCode")
                    {

                        countrycode = (reader.ReadElementString());
                    }
                if (reader.Name == "CountryName")
                    {

                        countryname = (reader.ReadElementString());
                    }
                if (reader.Name == "PostalCode")
                    {

                        postalcode = (reader.ReadElementString());
                    }



            //populate table data from extracted values

            //connect to db
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connXML"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            con.Open();

            //send extracted data to db
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into INV_HEADER VALUES ('" + org_id + "','" + org_desig + "', '" + org_name + "' , '" + add_1 + "', '" + add_2 + "', '" + add_3 + "', '" + cityname + "', '" + countrycode + "', '" + countryname + "', '" + postalcode + "')";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            reader.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: WOAH CAPS AREN'T NEEDED ALL THE TIME

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Have you confirmed that the values are being read from the xml file correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are inserting the values after every reader.Read(). Try to do an insert after your while loop.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string org_id;
    string org_desig;
    string org_name;
    string add_1;
    string add_2;
    string add_3;
    string cityname;
    string countrycode;
    string countryname;
    string postalcode;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Load the XML file
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("PXMLF-8612013050420130606105906.xml");

        //  Loop over the XML file
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //  look for element
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                //  If the element is the one required
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    case "OrganizationID":
                        org_id = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break;
                    case "OrganisationDesignator":
                        org_desig = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break;
                    case "OrganizationName1":
                        org_name = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break;
                    case "AddressLine1":
                        add_1 = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break;
                    case "AddressLine2":
                        add_2 = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break;
                    case "AddressLine3":
                        add_3 = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break;
                    case "CityName":
                        cityname = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break;
                    case "CountryCode":
                        countrycode = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break;
                    case "CountryName":
                        countryname = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break;
                    case "PostalCode":
                        postalcode = (reader.ReadElementString());
                        break; 
                }
            }
        }

        //connect to db
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connXML"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        con.Open();

        //send extracted data to db
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into INV_HEADER VALUES ('" + org_id + "','" + org_desig + "', '" + org_name +
                          "' , '" + add_1 + "', '" + add_2 + "', '" + add_3 + "', '" + cityname + "', '" +
                          countrycode + "', '" + countryname + "', '" + postalcode + "')";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: arjen it worked.  Good (y)

Comment: @user2660107 A vote would be appreciated. :)

Comment: hehe sorry im new in hre did not knw to vote .... :D not one wud hav givn two if cud hav

Answer (score 0):

It looks like reader.Read() method loops only one iteration. Why don't you run it in debug mode and see if the variables are actually being set to values retrieved from the Xml nodes? If they are getting values correctly, then next thing to do is to check your CommandText. Copy the SQL statement from CommandText and paste it to SQL Server Management Studio and run it to see if it is actually inserting the record (assuming you are using SQL Server).

Comment: updataes : Yess values are being read from the xml @paddyd.
Values are seen to be inserted in database too. BUT,not in respective columns.